# Como puedo cambiar el código de todas las paginas a la vez

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una web programada a pelo (sin CMS ni nada) y necesito colocarle un banner de publicidad pero no quiero editar cada archivo html

Hay alguna manera de editar todas las paginas a la vez?

Gracias de antededo

Comment: Me parece que con include puedes "incrustar" el php donde tienes el baner en las demás páginas: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

Comment: Pero tengo que editarlo en cada archivo igualmente. Yo quiero que se edite solo una vez y no perder el tiempo

Comment: Bueno, quizás si nos muestras algo de código que hayas utilizado para intentar llegar a la solución, podemos revisarlo e intentar ayudarte. Tu pregunta no es muy específica. Revisa estos tips: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Si estas en PC descarga el editor [NOTEPAD ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.7.1.html)

1) Tienes que identificar el patron donde quieres insertar el banner (sino existe, dicho patron no sera posible hacerlo en automatico)

Tomando como ejemplo el siguiente código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mi CMS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- AQUI VA MI BANNER CHIDO ONE -->

</body>
</html>
```

vamos a suponer que el patron a remplazar es:

```
<body>
    <!-- AQUI VA MI BANER -->
```

2) Abre página html en [NOTEPAD ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.7.1.html)

y seleccionas tal cual *EL PATRON*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3) A continuación vas al menu `Buscar` (`search`) en la opción `buscar en archivos` (`Find in files`) o tecla rapida `Ctrl + Shift + F`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4) Escribe el valor con el que vas definir tu banner en el campo `Remplazar con` (`Replace with`)

- En el campo `Filtros` (`Filters`) agrega el comodin *.html
- En el campo `Directorio` (`Directory`) indica en que carpeta estan tus archivos html
- Verifica tus valores y presiona en el boton `Remplazar por archivo` (`Replace in Files`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*PARA MAC BUSCA UN EDITOR IDE que cuente con la funcionalidad de REMPLAZO POR ARCHIVO.

Saludos.